# Is my workout plan good ? (16 year old male)

Tags: workout

http://evilcyber.com/fitness/home-workout-plan-for-teenagers/

I have started doing this workout plan. Is it OK? I aim on all muscles, but mostly on abs and biceps.

Me:

~57.5 kg
172 cm
16 years old

By the way instead of pull-ups, I do chin-ups by holding over the pull up bar a few seconds and then slowly going down. (That's because I can't really do actual pull ups yet)

Answer (score 2):

As a complete beginner, a good workout routine would ideally to conform to these points:

- Linear progression. Since the workload is light compared to your absolute physical potential when you're a beginner, you have the capacity to completely recover from one workout to the next while adapting too. Aim to increase workload each workout or each week.
- Full body workout. Because of the above points regarding recovery and adaptation, there isn't a point in doing workout splits. This doesn't mean you have to do the same workout multiple times a week, but each workout should train the full body. As a young male beginner you will recover in about 48 hours so leaving more time between training the various muscle groups is a waste.
- Three workouts per week. This follows from the above point. You do still need recovery. You might feel like you can handle two full body workouts on consecutive days after a few weeks (when delayed onset muscle soreness is no longer an issue) but doing this regularly would accumulate stress exceeding recovery.

The program you linked conforms to this to some extent. You get a full body workout, you can do three workouts per week and some form of linear progression can be achieved by increasing the number of repetitions.

That said, I don't think it is ideal. If you have some option to join a gym where you have access to a power or squat rack, bench, barbells and weight plates, I would strongly encourage you to go there and follow a program that focuses on progressive overload and linear progression through increases in weight on the bar. You will quickly exhaust your potential for progress with only the bodyweight exercises and end up on high repetition sets, which aren't very useful for an increase in strength. Gaining muscle is a response of the body to stress imposed on it, when neurological adaptations and improved form no longer suffice. Doing these bodyweight exercises without some way of providing a linear increase in loading will mostly provide adaptations for endurance. If a gym is not an option, seek ways to provide this overload in a different way. Weight plates on your upper back during push-ups (not very convenient), a dipping belt with weights on pull-ups and/or chin-ups (works well) and maybe dumbbells or kettlebells to hold during squats. You'd find pretty soon, however, that the investment in material would have better served for a gym membership.

For abs, the program suggests crunches. While certainly a popular exercise, much is to be said for the bicycle maneuver, which has shown in a study to have much higher EEG readings from the muscles. It can be done without equipment. I myself also like ab rollouts using a wheel, which is inexpensive. Inform yourself of proper form since it can be taxing on the back, and start with low repetitions (e.g. 2 sets of 5 reps) or you may find yourself having trouble rising from bed the next day.

I found this blogpost to provide a good overview of what constitutes a decent beginner routine: http://www.aworkoutroutine.com/beginner-workouts/

If a gym membership is absolutely not an option, seek out various bodyweight routines and judge them based on what I told you and what you read in that post. If you can use a gym, I'd highly recommend Starting Strength or StrongLifts 5x5 as a starting point.